# C++ Belong Condition

Tags: c++

I need to do an if condition with ∉ (not belong to)

The condition:

```
if tj ∉ A(fi) where A(fi) contains some elements
```

Example:

```
A(f1)= t1, t2 A(f2)= t1, t3
```

so if t3 ∉ A(f1) do something.

My problem is I don't know how to do the ∉ in C++

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the answers.

I have one more questions but I don't know if it's really possible or if I dream too much. I need to run my program many times but each time the elements inside the A(fi) will change.

I know it's possible to do random with 0 and 1. So I was thinking that instead of put t1 it will be replace by 0 or 1 but after I don't know how to write the order.

Like I have A(f1) ={1, 0,1,0} and A(f2)={0,1,1,0} so t1 appear in A(f1), t2 appear in A(f2), t3 appear in A(f1) and A(f2) and so on.

For the set function it writes:

"Sets are containers that store unique elements following a specific order." So it might be possible to give a name to the order

So my question is do you think is it possible and how I can link t1, t2, t3...?

I find another problem is that I might to create more set to have more than 2 or A(fi), the number is not in advance. I didn't find how is it possible to create a different number of set at different time. is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Let's try to narrow down your question. Have you got as far in your design as "What type should t1, t2, t3, f1, f2, and A() be?"

Comment: We do have `std::includes`.

Comment: @chris That is pretty neat, I added an example using `std::includes` to my answer to see how it compares.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) to this, here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::set<std::string> myset;

  myset.insert( "t1") ;
  myset.insert( "t2") ;

  if( myset.count( "t2") != 0 )
  {
     std::cout << "Set contains t2" << std::endl; 
  }

  if( myset.count( "t3") != 0 )
  {
     std::cout << "Set contains t3" << std::endl; 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and an example using [std::includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v1 {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4" };
  std::vector<std::string> v2 {"t2", "t4"};
  std::vector<std::string> v3 {"t3"};  

  std::cout << "v1 contains the follows elments of v2:" << std::endl ;
  for (auto i : v2){
     std::cout << i << ' ';
     std::cout << ": " << std::includes(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end()) << std::endl ;
  }

  std::cout << "v1 contains the follows elments of v3:" << std::endl ;
  for (auto i : v3){
     std::cout << i << ' ';
     std::cout << ": " << std::includes(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end()) << std::endl ;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) container to store a set of elements. Then use the method `count` and check its return value for zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `A` is a function that returns a `std::set` (or a reference to a `std::set`):

```
auto& s = A(f1);
if(s.find(t3) == s.end())
  std::cout << "Not in set\n";
```